# AngularJS / ui-router - Looping over states, with resolves, needs a closure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, closures

I'm building my states dynamically in our AngularJS app, using ui-router.

Given an array of states like this (for example):

```
const dynamicStates = [
    {name: 'alpha', template: '123'},
    {name: 'bravo', template: '234'}
];
```

And then building the states like so (for example):

```
const states = [];
dynamicStates.forEach(state => 
   states.push(
       state: state.name,
       resolve: {
           templateDetails: ['Service', (Service) =>
               Service.getTemplate(state.template)
                   .then(response => response)     
           ]
       }
   )
})
states.forEach(states => $stateProvider.state(state));
```

state.template, within the resolve function is always '123'. I'm certain that this is a closure issue, but I can't get my head around exactly how the resolve works (what is it actually returning), and so can't figure out how to close the scope around my state.template.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: it would help to rename few things first. Your `state` is an object, a key, and a function.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey - Thanks, but as both code snippets say, these are examples, with the key concepts included, but nothing else. My states are also not named 'alpha' and 'bravo', and my templates are not called '123', '234'. Further, even if this was correct, it wouldn't "help" me find a solution by renaming them.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the solution.

In each resolve, I created another function which calls closureAroundTemplateId, and returns the template ID value. That is then passed to the next resolve function which actually gets the template details.

I did this (as above, example code):

```
function closureAroundTemplateId (type) {
    return function(){
        return type['template'];
    }
}

const states = [];
dynamicStates.forEach(state => 
   states.push(
       state: state.name,
       resolve: {
           templateId: closureAroundFormTemplateId(state),
           templateDetails: ['Service', 'templateId', (Service, templateId) =>
               Service.getTemplate(templateId)
                  .then(response => response)     
               ]
   )
})
states.forEach(states => $stateProvider.state(state));
```